# Running a Random Number generator in parallel? Will this speed up a computation?

Tags: random-number-generation, random-walk

I'm calculating basically a multidimensional random walk problem.   To get more accuracy, I need larger systems (more dimensions), which requires longer time.  To speed up the calculation, I'm delving into parallel computing for the first time.

I call the fortran random number generator frequently.    It occurred to me that I might split the random number  generator off from the rest of the program and run it in parallel. Of course, the generated random numbers would be stored in a shared memory location.  Does it seem like this could potentially speed up the computation?  Does a random number generator take up a large fraction of the CPU in a random walk problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random number generator is rarely the limiting factor in computational science. RNGs are usually quite simple and fast, a few dozen instructions, really. If you are doing anything even remotely complicated in your code with these random numbers, then the bottleneck is there.

Comment: Probably want to profile your code to see where the bottlenecks. But looking ahead, a question for you: If you're thinking about moving to higher number of dimensions, how are you envisioning parallelizing your model?

Comment: @rural I don't know if there is a clever way to parallelize this model. However, I do many samples or realizations of the random walk, and I average over such realizations. I could create independent realizations of the model and send each realization to a different thread. I'd call this the brain-dead method of parallelization. The problem there is that I have a big system. Hence, if I create multiple realizations, each realization has a system state that must be stored in memory, and I will soon take up the entire memory. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Sounds as if you have an 'embarrassingly parallel' model so I assume you're targeting a multinode system. The only advice I can share is to take advantage of existing strategies for distribution of the starting seeds to each processor. That way you avoid the unlikely-theoretically-but-likely-when-you-least-expect-it issue of two processes that you intend to be independent realizations actually sharing the same sequence of variates.

Comment: If I understand correctly, @Chris needs to generate a random array which needs to be shared among the threads. Is your problem similar to the Heston problem, Chris?

Comment: @rural  Yes, embarrassingly parallel, but limited by total memory.  I'm learning about sending threads to different cores, but haven't encountered the term "multinode" yet. Abdullah, I'm afraid I don't know about the Heston problem. The various realizations are totally independent; they don't share anything, but the parent thread must sum the results of all realizations.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Chris, all I meant by 'multinode' was a simple distributed system. I think I might have misread you. You seem to want to generate a giant list of random numbers, then to have one or more processes access them. I'm sure you have a good reason for taking that approach but I don't know what it is and haven't run into it myself. Typically they, the random variates, are generated on demand. Best of luck, I'm eager to see what you learn.

Comment: When you say "random numbers", I assume that what you really do is a Monte Carlo method? Or are you really just sampling at random locations and evaluating a model at these locations?